# Is there any test result reporting tool for TestNG & Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: selenium, testng

I am using TestNG and Selenium webdriver via Java.

Is there any tool that can help generate detailed test results, for example, suppose I have a test case that fails more often than not, is there a tool that can statistically report those test cases that fail more often than the others like in a graph, or pie chart, etc?

Comment: Have you explore Allure? http://allure.qatools.ru/

Comment: @log_file Nope I haven't. I wil ltake a look. Thanks!

Comment: I think this link might be of some help, as this report gives the Pass Rate per Test Case basis (which you are looking for). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853644/selenium-java-displaying-suite-results-listed-by-run-instead-than-by-test-ca

Comment: Cross-posted on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999308/test-result-reporting

Answer (score 2):

**XL Testview**

Have a look at [XL Testview](https://xebialabs.com/products/xl-testview/) from [XebiaLabs](https://xebialabs.com/).

> Test analytics and decision support that spans testing tools
>
> - See all your test results in one single dashboard
> - Analyze test results across multiple test tools
> - Track release metrics and quality trends over time
> - Use real-time quality data to make the best go/no-go release decisions

I havent used it, but seems to track results over time. Seems pretty interesting.

**Test Result Analyzer**

Or have a look a the [Test Result Analyzer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Test+Results+Analyzer+Plugin) plugin for [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/).

> Many of us have a requirement of knowing the execution status of a
>   test package , test class or test-method across multiple builds. This
>   plugin is an implementation of the said requirement and shows a table
>   containing the executions status of a package,class or a test-method
>   across builds.

This plugin supports jUnit and TestNG results sets. Looks like the minimum you want and it is free. :)

Answer (score 0):

**ATUT Reporter help you provide bar chart and graph, you just need to add listeners in your class. go through this link**

```
 http://automationtestingutilities.blogspot.in/p/reporting.html
```